# How to initialize a "Boost interprocess managed windows shared memory" member variable?

Tags: boost

I need to access a shared memory segment created by another process. In Boost documentation I couldn't find how to initialize a member variable. As all the examples were explained in int main(), the use of member variable is not show.
I'm using a managed windows shared memory & I need it to be a member variable with initialization in constructor. Below I've shown how it's done as a local variable,

```
boost::interprocess::managed_windows_shared_memory shm(boost::interprocess::open_only, "ShrdMemKey");
```

But how do I initialize the same in c'tor if I declared it as a member variable.

```
class ShrdMem
{
private:
  boost::interprocess::managed_windows_shared_memory shm; 
public:
  ShrdMem();
};

ShrdMem::ShrdMem()
{
  // Need shm to be initialized in c'tor.
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has syntax for providing constructor parameters to member variables.

```
ShrdMem::ShrdMem()
  : shm(boost::interprocess::open_only, "ShrdMemKey")
{
  // Here, shm is initialised according to the parameters passed above
}
```

It's very handy for situations like this. If you need to initialise multiple members, just separate them with a comma.